# Threading UI Update (not the invoke required question)

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, multithreading

I have a case where I am getting lots of sockets requests coming in. I would like to update the UI 3 seconds after the last socket request has come in. E.g If socket request comes in and the previous one was only 2 seconds ago it should clear the UI Update and start waiting for 3 seconds.

Notes:
Each Socket Request comes in on a different thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the UI in a [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) (set the timer's [`SynchronizingObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject.aspx) property to your form) with a three-second interval and reset it whenever you receive a request.

**EDIT**: On further thought, you should use a [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx), which is less convenient then `Timers.Timer` but is more lightweight, and is completely thread-safe.  In its callback, you'll have to call `form.BeginInvoke` to switch to the UI thread.

Each time you receive a request, you would run `timer.Change(3000, -1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `System.Timers.Timer`.  Each time a request comes in you reset the timer for 3 seconds.  When the timer goes off update the UI.  The timer has to be accessed by every thread so you will need to protect it with a mutex.